# При нажатии на кнопку переход на другую страницу и выбор необходимого option

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html-select

Есть две страницы. Допустим, на первой три кнопки - "BMW", "Mazda", "Toyota". А на второй странице select с option: "BMW", "Mazda" и "Toyota". Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "BMW" шел переход на вторую страницу и сразу выбирался соответствующий option. На JS или PHP.

Comment: Приведите код демонстрирующий, как у вас реализованы кнопки, чтобы можно было говорить более предметно. Первое, что приходит в голову - кнопки реализовать ссылками типа `/page2.php?car=BMW`, `/page2.php?car=Mazda`, `/page2.php?car=Toyota`, а на странице `page2.php` обрабатывать параметр `$_GET['car']`.

Comment: Да неказисто оформлены - <a href="#" class="button">кнопка</a>. Понял Вас, спасибо) буду копать в сторону гет-запросов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select.php?item=BMM
в файле select бери POST или GET и вставляй в option